# How to use Alias and aggregate or concat

Tags: mysql, sql

1 user has multiple records in tbl_activity and there is diplay_name, I would like to concat all of them il a columns name activity_name

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_user` 

INNER JOIN `tbl_user_authassignment` 
ON  `tbl_user`.`id` =  `tbl_user_authassignment`.`userid`

INNER JOIN `tbl_activity` 
`tbl_activity`.`id` AS 'activityid'
ON  `tbl_user`.`id` =  `tbl_activity`.`vendor_id`  


WHERE  `tbl_user_authassignment`.`itemname` = 'vendor'
```

Comment: which DMBS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (which is suggested by your syntax), you can use `group_concat()`.  I don't know which fields you care about but it is something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, group_concat(a.acitvityid) as activityids
FROM `tbl_user` u INNER JOIN
     `tbl_user_authassignment` ua
     ON u.`id` =  ua.`userid` INNER JOIN      
     `tbl_activity` a
      ON u.`id` =  a.`vendor_id`  
WHERE  ua`.`itemname` = 'vendor'
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's `MySQL` syntax and so you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for this purpose

```
SELECT tu.*, 
xx.`id` AS 'activityid',
xx.activity_name
FROM `tbl_user` tu

INNER JOIN `tbl_user_authassignment` tua
ON  tu.`id` =  tua.`userid`

INNER JOIN ( 
select `vendor_id`,
`id`,
group_concat(diplay_name) as activity_name
from `tbl_activity` 
group by `vendor_id`) xx ON  tu.`id` =  tua.`vendor_id`  

WHERE  tua.`itemname` = 'vendor';
```